# Observable from ZoneAvarePromise Angular2

Tags: angular

I trying to make chain of request, fill result arr by data and parse it.
In case with promises it's normal, but Angular 2 use RxJs with theirs subscribers etc.

So I try to make this

```
 private getPatientPrefPharmacies(patientId: string): Observable {
    return this._http.get(this._config.getPatientFeauturesJsonUrl(patientId, this.preferredPharmaciesPropName))
        .map(res => {
           return Observable.of(this.getAggregatedPatientPrefPharmData(res.json()) );
        })
        .catch(this.handleError)
}


 private getAggregatedPatientPrefPharmData (patientPrefPharmList: Object[]) {
    let chain: Promise = Promise.resolve(),
        results = [];

    patientPrefPharmList.forEach((patPharm) => {
        chain = chain
            .then(() => {
                return new Promise((res, rej) => {
                    this.getPharmacyDetail(patPharm.pharmacyId)
                        .subscribe(
                            pharmData => {
                                if (pharmData.result.pharmacy[0]) {
                                    patPharm.pharmData = pharmData.result.pharmacy[0];
                                    res(patPharm)
                                }
                            },
                                err => rej(err)
                            )
                });
            })
            .then(result => {
                results.push(result);
            })
    });

    return chain.then(() => {
        return results
    })
}
```

And subscribe for it

```
 this._prefPharmSrvc.getPatientPrefPharmacies(this.patientId)
            .subscribe(
                prefPharmList => this.patientPrefPharmList = prefPharmList,
                err => console.log(err)
            );
```

But I got strange object: **ScalarObservable** that contains in value field  another very strange object:   **ZoneAwarePromise**  and in this object exist property __zone_symbol__value  with my results.

I can parse data from this, but I don't sure that is correct. Maybe I did something wrong and much better way exist?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's because you return an observable within the callback of the `map` operator:

```
return this._http.get(this._config.getPatientFeauturesJsonUrl(patientId, this.preferredPharmaciesPropName))
    .map(res => {
       return Observable.of(this.getAggregatedPatientPrefPharmData(res.json()) ); // <---
    })
    .catch(this.handleError)
```

Either you return a raw value (not an observable) in the `map` operator callback either you use the `flatMap` operator if you need an observable.

Here is the way I would refactor your code:

```
private getPatientPrefPharmacies(patientId: string): Observable {
  return this._http.get(this._config.getPatientFeauturesJsonUrl(patientId, this.preferredPharmaciesPropName))
    .flatMap(res => {
      return Observable.fromPromise(this.getAggregatedPatientPrefPharmData(res.json()));
    })
    .catch(this.handleError);
}
```

Comment: Have to resolve promise in promise.
from, mergeMap help me resolve that.
https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/mergemap.html